# EditText not updating consistently in Async task

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-edittext

I am writing an android app that plays a video file using a videoview and receives data from another device via UDP packets and updates info on the display. I need to set the display to landscape while the video is playing but by doing so the display is not updated as expected. This does occasionally happen when in portrait but the problem can be recreated every time by setting to landscape.

Hopefully the short example below can explain the problem. It uses an ASync tasks to listen for a message on port 2222 and then updates an edittext when it is received.

```
public class UDPTest extends Activity {

EditText udpMessage;

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    udpMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.udpMessage);
    new myAsyncServer().execute(); 
}   

private class myAsyncServer extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String udpRecieved = null;
        byte[] udpMsg = new byte[1000];
        DatagramPacket dPacket = new DatagramPacket(udpMsg, udpMsg.length);
        DatagramSocket dSocket = null;
        try {
            dSocket = new DatagramSocket(2222);
            Log.e("Async", "Before");
            dSocket.receive(dPacket);
            Log.e("Async", "After");

            udpRecieved = new String(udpMsg, 0, dPacket.getLength());
            Log.e("Packet received", udpRecieved);
            publishProgress(udpRecieved);

        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (dSocket != null) {
                dSocket.close();
            }
        }  
        return null;   
    }   

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);     
        Log.e("In OnProgress", values[0]);
        udpMessage.setText(values[0]);
    }     
}
```

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".UDPTest" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/udpMessage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:ems="10" />
```

With the screen orientation not defined (setRequestedOrientation commented out), run the program, send a packet over port 2222  to the devices ip address (I used PacketSender) and the edit text is updated straight away. With the orientation set to landscape, ie un comment setRequestedOrientation) the packet has to be sent 2 or 3 times before the edittext is updated.

From the Log messages inserted into the code I can see that each time the packet is sent, the packet and message (I sent 'Help') are received, onProgressUpdate called with the correct message but the edittext is not changed.

**LogCat from portrait view shows:**

```
12-13 10:11:56.123: E/Async     (32111) : Before

Send packet

12-13 10:12:06.738: E/Async     (32111) : After

12-13 10:12:06.743: E/Packet received   (32111) : Help

12-13 10:12:06.743: E/In OnProgress (32111) : Help

EditText updated
```

**LogCat from Landscape view is:**

```
12-13 10:39:57.163: E/Async     (4328): Before

Send packet

12-13 10:40:03.188: E/Async     (4328): After

12-13 10:40:03.188: E/Packet received   (4328): Help

12-13 10:40:03.193: E/In OnProgress (4328): Help

12-13 10:40:03.193: E/Async     (4328): Before

EditText not updated 

Send packet again   

12-13 10:40:06.463: E/Async     (4328): After

12-13 10:40:06.463: E/Packet received   (4328): Help

12-13 10:40:06.463: E/In OnProgress (4328): Help

Edit text updated
```

I don't think this is entirely related to the screen orientation but cannot figure out why.

EDIT:
I can actually rule out the UDP Packet part of this. If i just remove all of the code in doInBackground and replace with

```
         Log.e("Async", "Before");
         publishProgress("Test");
         Log.e("Async", "After");
```

The same thing happens. Set to portrait, the code in doInBackground is executed once, onProgressUpdate is called, edittext changedand the log reflects that. When set to Landscape though, the code is executed twice, onProgressUpdate is called twice and only on the second time is the edittext updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try change text in OnThread

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            text.setText("GS"); 
            }
        });
```

Comment: Sorry, no change. When set to landscape, I still need to send the same packet twice before the edittext is updated. Thanks though!

Comment: if values[0] is not string you can't update and you can try this some times working.
udpMessage.setText(values[0]+"");

Comment: I did think of that, values[0] is always a string